# No such file or directory

Tags: python, pytorch

```py
import os
from PIL import Image
path='D:/SomeExperiments/KITTRawData/2011_09_26/2011_09_26_drive_0091_sync/image_03/data/0000000100.jpg'
with open(path,'rb') as f:
    pass
```

error as below

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/SomeExperiments/KITTRawData/2011_09_26/2011_09_26_drive_0091_sync/image_03/data/0000000224.jpg'
```

but I can find this path on my computer:
[image]

Comment: Probably because you're using forward slashes when you should be using backslashes. Don't forget to escape them or add a `r` in front of the string literal.

Comment: Are you sure you're using that program? Your screenshot shows ```0000000000``` to ```0000000015```, your program opens ```0000000100.jpg``` and your error states it can't find ```0000000224.jpg```. Also we can't check if files are actually jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible solution**

Hold the `shift` key and right click on the image file. Select `copy as path`. Then paste the copied path into your python script. This SHOULD work for sure.

**Possible reasons for the error**

1. You are using slashes instead of backslashes - My version of windows and python supports using slashes but I'm not sure if it supports all.
2. File extension mismatch - Maybe your files are `.jpeg` and yet you are trying `.jpg` in your script. Path is not case sensitive in Windows but it's always a good practice to use correct case in the path, for example if your file is `aBc.TXT` you should use the exact same name not `abc.txt`.

Comment: According to your reply, I  already correct it. Thank you very much